# Find the minimum of $(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)$ where $a,b,c\geq 0$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Find the minimum of:
>
> $$(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)  \ \ \  a,b,c\geq 0$$

Knowing that $$ab+bc+ac=27$$

I tried my best using QM-AM-GM inequalities, Cauchy-Schwarz, etc. I tried also to do it with partial derivatives but it's too long. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: My initial thought: Let $x=ab,y=bc,z=ac$, so that the constraint function is $x+y+z=27$. Then $xy=ab^2 c=b^2 z\implies b^2=x y/z$ and similarly $a^2=xz/y$, $c^2=yz/x$. That makes the objective function more annoying, but it still seems tractable.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the contest? Or some other evidence that the contest is not currently active. I have no reason to think that it is, but we have this rule :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen it's just a simulation of math team national italian olympiad. It's not even an official competition :) .The true Olympiads are in May as you can see here http://olimpiadi.dm.unibo.it/ (but the site is italian).

Comment: Thanks, Eureka.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We note that $(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)$ is a symmetric function with respect to $a$, $b$, and $c$. We rewrite it by using the elementary symmetric polynomials $a+b+c$, $ab+bc+ca$ and $abc$: 
$$\begin{align}
(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)&=(ab+bc+ca-1)^2+(a+b+c-abc)^2\\
&=26^2+(a+b+c-abc)^2\geq 26^2=676
\end{align}$$
where the condition $ab+bc+ac=27$ has been applied.

Hence the minimum is $676$ as soon as we show that there are $a,b,c\geq 0$ such that $ab+bc+ac=27$ and $a+b+c=abc$.
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I don't manage to continue, please help me

Comment: @Robert Z Amazing! +1

Comment: How had you this idea ? +1

Comment: @Eureka The minimum is $26^2=676$ as soon as we show that there are $a,b,c\geq 0$ such that $ab+bc+ac=27$ and $a+b+c=abc$.

Comment: @Robert Z Thank you so much, can I ask you how did you come up with this? Because it doesn't seem really intuitive. Is it just a question of experience or there are some tricks that I should learn?

Comment: $(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)$ is a symmetric function with respect to $a$, $b$ and $c$. Try to rewrite it using the elementary symmetric polynomials $a+b+c$, $ab+bc+ca$ and $abc$.

Comment: Interestingly, these conditions do not constrain a unique $(a,b,c)$ for which that minimum is achieved; rather, there's an entire one-dimensional family of such minimal solutions. I don't know if any of these are particularly nice, e.g., rational solutions. (For some explicit solutions, one can look for cases where two of the three variables are equal.)

Comment: I have a rather direct proof of the identity used by @Robert Z : use twice what is called Diophantes equality $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac−bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2$ (which can be explained as two ways of writing the squared norm ( = squared module) of $(a+ib)(c+id)$)... Or, said in an even simpler way  take the squared norm of both sides of relationship $(1+ia)(1+ib)(1+ic)=(1-ab-bc-ca)+(a+b+c-abc)i$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Nice remark.

Comment: Good job. You even managed to convince Michael about the usefulness of elementary symmetric polynomials - something I failed the last time I tried.

Answer (score 4):

A simple supplement to Robert's nice answer. With the aid of the following plot I'm sure you all can prove that when $a+b+c=12=abc$ the polynomial
$$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=x^3-12x^2+27x-12$$
has three positive zeros $a,b,c$ :-)

[image]

Comment: Adding this because it was not immediately obvious to me how to prove that Robert's lower bound can be achieved. I'm sure there are nice trick ways of doing that. But, it really is simple.

Comment: Thanks for this supplement (+1)