# Find the minum of the expression $V=abc$ when $a+b+c=25$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

Recently, I have found these two problems:

> The $12$ edges of a parallelepiped are integers. Given that their sum is $100$, what is the maximum value of the volume, or:
> $$V=abc$$

I have posted both hare because I think the methods for finding the solutions are similar (let me know if I have to open another question).

I can't completely figure out a solution to the first problem, while for the second, I can say: $a+b+c=25 \Longleftrightarrow c=25-a-b$ and so, substituing:
$$V=abc=ab\cdot(25-a-b)=25ab-a^2b-ab^2$$
But here I am another time stucked. Any iodea? Do I have to use inequalities such as C-S and Am-GM?

Thank you.

Comment: The first one is (for example) answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3179770/find-the-minimum-of-1a21b21c2-where-a-b-c-geq-0

Comment: @MartinR: I will delete that part; thank you. What about the second?

Answer (score 1):

AM-GM inequality can be used here.

We have $$\frac{a+b+c}{3} \ge \sqrt[3]{abc}$$

Hence $$\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3} \right)^3 \ge abc$$

Check the condition for equality of AM-GM inequality to hold to decide the value of $a, b$ and $c$.

Comment: So, how can we reach the maximum value?

Comment: when does equality hold for AM-GM inequality? You can find the solution [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality)